# uiwebview in every tableviewcells

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiwebview

I need to display each webview in each of the tableviewcell in my Uitableview.When using the below code,when there are 2 elements,the first cell is empty but second cell is correct.

hrs and hrsHtml contains all values,the problem is only the last data is displaying in their appropriate cell in tableview.Other cells are just blank.

Also is total cells is 2,first we can only been able to see the 2nd cell only,but after scrolling tableview reloads and 2nd cell disappears and 1st cell gets displayed.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return [brId count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];

    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:hrs];

    hrsHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  <font size=\"2\"  face=\"Arial\">%@  </font>",[html objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    [hrs loadHTMLString:hrsHtml baseURL:nil];

    return cell;
}
```

Screenshot when tableview appears,Only webview in cell 2

[image]

Screenshot when tableview scrolls,Only webview in cell 1,cell 2 disappears

[image]

Comment: Have you check that hrs and hrsHtml are not nil using break points at runtime?

Comment: @Sumanth hrs and hrsHtml contains all values,the problem is only the last data is displaying in their appropriate cell in tableview.Other cells are just blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] ;
    }

    hrs = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,320,84)];

    hrs.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    hrs.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    hrsHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  <font size=\"2\"  face=\"Arial\">%@  </font>",[html objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    [hrs loadHTMLString:hrsHtml baseURL:nil];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:hrs];

    hrsHtml = nil;

    return cell;

}
```

Now the webview loads correctly in every tableviewcell.

Answer (score 1):

Since `hrs` and `hrsHtml` are single objects, you only have one of each even though you have multiple cells.  If you modify `hrs`, it will change for all cells since they seem to be sharing it.  (Unless you have other code somewhere that changes the objects that those variables point to.)

Another odd thing is that you use a `brId` array to determine the number of rows and a `html` array to get the row content.  If those ever get out of synchronization, you will have problems.

Also, you should only add a subview to a cell when you create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have problem in initializing cell try below code

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,But it doesn't make any change